# Count value in every day. Help me, I'm newbie

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how do i query mongodb to be so .. thank

```
{
    status: A
    date: 1/1
},
{
    status: A
    date: 1/1
}
{
    status: B
    date: 1/1
}
{
    status: B
    date: 2/1
}
{
    status: B
    date: 5/1
}
```

Result:

```
 {
     date: 1/1,
     statusA: 2,
     statusB: 1
 }
  {
     date: 2/1,
     statusA: 0,
     statusB: 1
 }
  {
     date: 3/1,
     statusA: 0,
     statusB: 0
 }  {
     date: 4/1,
     statusA: 0,
     statusB: 0
 } 
 {
     date: 5/1,
     statusA: 0,
     statusB: 1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$group`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$date",
      statusA: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: [ "$status","A"] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      statusB: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { $eq: [ "$status", "B" ]},
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-8iolZsyDn3)**

Comment: Your answer is good, but how do I get its missing days and null value.? thank

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` pipline API:

1. `group` element by `date` while counting statusA/B using `$sum` 1 or 0 depending on `$eq` conditon result
2. Then `project` the result to rename `_id` by `date` (as you expected in your exemple)

```js
db.collection.aggregate()
  .group({
      _id: "$date",
      statusA: { $sum: 
          { $cond: [{ $eq: [ "$status", "A" ]}, 1, 0 ]}
      },
      statusB: { $sum: 
          { $cond: [{ $eq: [ "$status", "B" ]}, 1, 0 ]}
      }
  })
  .project({
      date: "$_id",
      statusA: 1,
      statusB: 1,
      _id: 0
    });
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but how do I get its missing days and null value.? thank